# Sudo user without ability to login

Tags: authentication, passwords, permissions, sudo

I have a `main` user with home folder encryption enabled. To avoid typing long phrase each time I want to have another user with sudo privilege and weak password.

In the terminal I would first switch user to further do any admin work

```
main@machine$:su test
password:{entering weak password fast}
test@machine$: sudo some action 
[sudo] password for test: {entering weak password fast}
```

I want user `test` to be unable to login under any condition and that is:

- After OS start or reboot user `test` should not be displayed, and GUI exit to terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F3) should also not allow to login with `test`
- After `main` user with encrypted folder login, and lock session, user `test` should not be able to login by any means
- Any other condition unknown to me, the `main` home is decrypted and I don't want any other users to access the system and thus access the files

Bonus: Ideally if another user did login, the `main` should auto log out to protect it's home

**Please note** an answer like: "disable password for sudo for main user" is not a viable solution. Reason: if left machine unattended without locking the session, I don't want someone ability to sudo without password, a weak password from other user will give me time to come back :)

Comment: Multi user systems were not designed to operate within the constraints you have defined, your options are basically 1) implement you own auth system 2) redesign your criteria, ie: make the encrypted folder something you mount when needed instead of your home folder

Comment: I guess what I want to achieve is maybe a short sudo password vs long login password that protects home dir https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94626/194331 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94700/194331

Answer (score 1):

So far I've learned it's impossible or otherwise too complex setup.

Basically in other to confirm anything as other user, that user must be able to login. When a user is set to not have login it simply can't be used (sudo or not doesn't matter).

The solution I came up with, but haven't tested 100% yet is to use hardware USD key with fingerprint reader.

- The first time login of `main` user would have to provide a password to decrypt home, so key is not useful and that's desired behavior.
- There would not be other users to keep system 100% sealed
- required elevated `sudo` operation would be confirmed by a fingerprint

This approach satisfies "if left machine unattended without locking the session, I don't want someone ability to sudo without password"

The cons to the solution

- must carry the key all the time, when traveling, but at least still can perform sudo operations without a key just need to type long password
- USB port constantly occupied, my not be best for laptops with limited ports without docking station